# In Qt scribble example, how can I saving the drawing data

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In Qt scribble example (located in Qt examples/widgets/scribble/), user can draw any shape with pen color and pen width with mouse event.

```
void ScribbleArea::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling)
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
}

void ScribbleArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && scribbling) {
        drawLineTo(event->pos());
        scribbling = false;
    }
}
```

In the original example, the line drawn cannot be modified any more. I want to change it so that I can change line color/width after the lines are drawn, and also save the drawing as a "draft" so line color/width can be edited even open later.

My first thought is to save the points from mouse event and redraw shape every time an edit happens. There may be a lot of data to process if the drawing is not small and redrawing everything seems poor in efficiency. Is there a more elegant way out there to do this? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO, this is the way to go: to record the points and redraw them later. If concerned about performance, you could consider [`QPainter::drawPolyline`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawPolyline) as well. On modern H/W, this shouldn't be an issue for reasonable input. Additionally, before adding a new point, you can compare the new line segment with last recorded. If the lines are co-linear the new point can replace the old - achieving a bit of compression. I recommend to try this out and get a personal impression about the performance. This is at least a good chance "to get a feeling".

Comment: An alternative way could be a hybrid approach: The contents of drawing area is backed as `QPixmap` - only new input is drawn. Additionally, the points are recorded (e.g. in a `std::vector<QPoint>`). Thus, the recorded points can be saved to file/re-loaded, and used to redraw contents initially after loading (or after essential modifications). I believe, CAD software worked this way in the past before GPUs became common.